# Hampton Bay ceiling fan doesn't work properly with wall dimmer switch?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I recently installed a ceiling fan in our living room.  It's a Hampton Bay (68" without light kit).  The fan came with a remote control.  I don't like using the remote so I installed a wall dimmer switch (all other fans in home have dimmer switches and work fine).  I first installed a unlimited dimmer and got excessive motor hum.  I next installed a three position "fan" dimmer switch.  Fan would only work with dimmer in the highest position.  Replaced this dimmer switch with another brand of three position fan dimmer switch and same problem, will only work with dimmer switch in highest position.  While the fan will only work with the wall dimmer switch in the highest position, the fan is still variable speed with the remote.  However the goal is to eliminate the remote.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a wall fan control, you'll likely have to remove the remote fan control receiver from the unit.  The remote receiver in the fan housing controls the fan speed, and will not allow the wall control to override it.

In the most basic case, the remote receiver will have "input" wires connected to the standard household wiring (ungrounded, grounded, grounding).  The unit will then have "output" wires that connect to the fan, and/or light kit. Because of this, controlling the "input"  of the remote receiver will have no effect on the "output".

The procedure for removing the remote receiver will completely depend on the unit.

Answer (score 1):

To go along with what Tester mentioned, you are trying to turn your dimmer switch into a 3-way switch.  Which probably the dimmer switch in question and the remote are both not made for.  If you want both to control your fan then you probably need to get a kit that has a dimmer/switch and remote combo.  This way they can communicate with each other (with wall switch usually acting as the master).